# Highlight duplicates in every 3rd column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

To highlight duplicates in all columns in a Google Sheets, we apply the conditional formatting to the `A1:Z1000` range and format cells if `Custom formula is` `=COUNTIF($A:$Z,A1)>1`.

What if I only want to highlight duplicates in every 3rd column?

Comment: what are you really trying to do? is it practical to reference the columns in anther sheet?

Comment: @ti7 I need to highlight duplicates in every 3rd column, which are url addresses, so that my colleagues can instantly know a duplicate value they just entered already exists and then revert their addition. I currently have the conditional formatting check the entire sheets like the example I gave in the question. But the amount of columns grows day by day, and I don't want the sheets to continue to check columns which do not care about duplicates because that would make the sheets slow. Referencing other sheets would not be an option because the work needs to be done in the same sheets.

Comment: `and I don't want the sheets to continue to check columns which do not care about duplicates because that would make the sheets slow` This seems like a new requirement. would you please explain

Comment: @Tedinoz The more columns the sheets has to check for duplicates, the slower the checking process is. Therefore, I want the sheets to only check duplicates in every 3rd column and avoid checking other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an IF Statement to your Conditional Formatting.
Make use of the MOD function also.

```
MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1,3)=0
```

This divides the column number minus 1 by 3, then checks if the remainder is 0.

**e.g**.

- COLUMN A becomes 0.  0 MOD 3 = 0.
- COLUMN B becomes 1.  1 MOD 3 = 1.

For your conditional formatting that becomes:

`=IF(MOD(COLUMN(A1)-1,3)=0,COUNTIF($A:$Z,A1)>1,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks. That does highlight duplicates in every 3rd column only and answered my question. However, it still checks other columns for duplicates. For example, I entered `1` in column A and B, and the cell in column A is highlighted. But in that case, I don't want any highlight to occur. I want the sheets to avoid checking column B, C, E, F, H, I, ... so that the checking process can be faster. My question was not clear enough, and that's my bad. Sorry. My point is optimizing the performance of the sheets. If what I just described is possible, please let me know and I'll ask a new question.